# how to block , a dieferent web pages with active directory (SMB 2003)?

Tags: active-directory

we apreciate your help...
best regards!!

Comment: Sorry, I was going to try and tidy up the language/structure of the question but I've really got no idea what's being asked.

Answer (score 1):

Forget Active Directory, Look at DNS

It's not a particularly nice solution if you have a lot of them to block. Still possible though. Hopefully this explains how.

If you want to block entire domains you would:

1. Open the DNS Console
2. Expand Forward Lookup Zones
3. Create a new Forward Lookup Zone, as a Primary Zone
4. Give it the name of the domain you wish to block. e.g. annoyingdomain.com.

If you just want to block websites under domains you do almost the same:

1. Open the DNS Console
2. Expand Forward Lookup Zones
3. Create a new Forward Lookup Zone, as a Primary Zone
4. Give it the name matching the site you want to block. e.g. www.annoyingdomain.com.

This way, you could still send mail and access other resources as annoyingdomain.com, it's just the address for www.annoyingdomain.com which gets answered by your own DNS Server.

Like I said, not exactely a nice solution, but, if you just want to block a few sites like myspace of Facebook, and dont have the money to spend on an Appliance as Wesley Recommended

Although I will say an appliance is the better solution

HTH

Answer (score 0):

Use Group Policy to edit IE's Content Advisor settings. You may need the [ADM templates for IE](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=11ab3e81-6462-4fda-8ee5-fcb8264c44b1&displaylang=en). However, that will only work for Internet Explorer settings so you'll have to block all other browsers somehow. Really, your best bet will be an appliance (E.g. Websense) or proxy server (E.g. Squid Cache).